# php and javascript calculation

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I am just learning javascript and hope you guys can help me.

here are my codes

The code below is for displaying ingredient names from my database

```
<?php
$q = pg_query("Select * FROM tblingredients");
while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     echo '
     <li>
     <a href="#" onclick="showOrder(\''.$r_ing['ingredientid'].'\', '.$r_ing['ingprice'].'); return     false;">'.$r_ing['ingredientname'].'</a><br>             
    </li>';
    } 
?>
```

And then i have this separate code for displaying the name and price of the selected ingredient name above. When user clicks on the ingredient name above the below code will display the name as well as the price of the selected ingredients.

```
<?php 
$q_order = pg_query("Select * FROM tblingredients");
    while($r_order = pg_fetch_assoc($q_order)) {
    ?>
<div id="<?php echo $r_order['ingredientid'];?>" style="display: none;" class="cart_item">
<div class="item_amount">1x</div>
    <div class="item_name">
        <a href=""><?php echo $r_order['ingredientname']; ?></a> </div>
        <a title="Remove item" rel="tooltip" onclick="deleteItem(<?php echo $r_order['ingredientid'];?>)"    class="close" href="">×</a>
    <div class="item_cart_price"><?php echo $r_order['ingredientprice']; ?></div>
</div><!--cart_item-->
<?php $i++;} ?>
```

And then below is where i want to display the total price of the selected ingredients.

```
<div id="total"></div>
```

Here is my javascript code and this is my problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showOrder(id, price) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    total = parseInt(price, 10);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML += total;
};
</script>
```

What the javascript above does is just concatenate na price and won't add the price. 
Let's say if user clicks ingredient A with price 5, ingredient B with price 10, ingredient C with price 20

The total displays like this -> 51020

I am just learning javascript and trying to apply it into my php code. Thank you in advance for your answer.

Also i would like the selected ingredient removed if the user clicks on the X using the above code

```
<a title="Remove item" rel="tooltip" onclick="deleteItem(<?php echo $r_order['ingredientid'];?>)" class="close" href="">×</a>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The PHP code appears to be mixing logic and presentation; also, it is tightly coupled to a specific database (PostgreSQL). Consider using PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to decouple the database from the code. And consider using a PHP framework that splits logic from presentation. (I use XML and XSLT.)

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention im using postgresql as my database but the code displays fine on screen. it is just that the calculation is not working.

Comment: Once you have the calculation fixed, I *highly* recommend posting the code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as well, to get a suggestions for how it can be improved.

Comment: Thank you Dave, i hope someone will help me fix the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
function showOrder(id, price) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    price = parseInt(price, 10);
    oldTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById('total').innerHTML);
    if (isNaN(oldTotal)) {oldTotal = 0;}
    total = price + oldTotal;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
};
```

Comment: That means "Not a Number". What is the value of document.getElementById('total') exactly?

Comment: at current there is no value for total. calculation for total happens only after user select ingredient

Comment: now what if the user deselect the ingredient, how to deduct the selected ingredient to the total price?

Comment: I suppose you could call the same showOrder function but pass the inverse of the price.